# how to select random api by submit button in react

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, api

i select random data in api with button click , dont work my code 
a code need code in submitChange function

```
export class MemeGenerator extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  apiData: []
}
this.submitChange = this.submitChange.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount () {
fetch('https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
   this.setState({
     apiData: data
    })
    console.log(this.state.apiData)
  })}
```

OnChange Function ?????

```
submitChange () {
}
```

and render select img from api

```
render () {
return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.submitChange}>
      <button onClick={this.submitChange} value='Submit'>Gen</button>
   <div>
       <img src='http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg' onLoad={this.loadImg} />
   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
)}}
```

Comment: What is the issue, please clarify the issue or problem you are facing with examples

Comment: move/copy the code fom `componentDidMount` to the `submitChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class MemeGenerator extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  apiData: []
}
this.submitChange = this.submitChange.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount () { /* fetch something as default here to show user or nothing till user pushes Gen button*/}

    submitChange (name) {
    fetch(`https://api.imgflip.com/${name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       this.setState({
       apiData: data
       })
    console.log(this.state.apiData)
    })
    }

render () {
return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.submitChange}>
      /* you should decide whre to get this name from an array of names from state? hardcode enum ...*/
      <button onClick={this.submitChange({name})} value='Submit'>Gen</button>
   <div>
       <img src='http://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg' onLoad={this.loadImg} />
   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
)}}
```